# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm getting above error on below code.

```
@api guestFirstName; //getting these from parent component
@api guestLastName;
@api guestPhoneNumber;
@api guestCodeFromGuestMaster;
@api guestEmailFromGuestMaster;
```

//LWC code

```
   sendEmailAfterEvent() {
    const recordInput = { toSend: this.guestEmailFromGuestMaster, firstName: this.guestFirstName, lastName: this.guestLastName, phoneNumber: this.guestPhoneNumber }  //send parameters
    sendEmailToController(recordInput).then(response => {
        console.log('Email has been sent...!');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('facing error in sending email ',error.message.body); //If there is an error on response
    })

}
```

//APEX controller code

```
public with sharing class ControllerLwcExample {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void sendEmailToController(String toSend, string firstName, string lastName, Integer phoneNumber){
    try{
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toSend};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Booking Confirmation');
        String body = 'Dear ' + firstName + ', ';
        body += 'Your booking has been confirmed.';
        body += 'Please find the details below:';
        body += 'First Name: '+firstName;
        body += 'Last Name: '+lastName;
        body += 'Phone Number: '+phoneNumber;
        body += 'Regards';
        body += 'Hotel Hotel Hotel';
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

I don't find any problem with above code but still getting below error. Any help would be appreciated.

error:  **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')**

Comment: Wondering if the cause of the actual error is mail.setHtmlBody(body); in the Apex. I see that OP is not setting HTML, rather plain text. Perhaps it should be mail.setPlainTextBody(body);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have two errors.

The first is that you are trying to send an email from a cacheable method (which you can't do, as a cacheable cannot perform DML).

This will be causing an error. Change:

`@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` to `@AuraEnabled`

Then, this error is getting to the LWC component, and this is where you are getting the `body` issue. Javascript exceptions don't have a `body` property on the `message`

Change: `error.message.body` to `error.message`

(Either that or try Phil's comment) (`error.body.message`)

Comment: Is it not `error.body.message`?

Comment: Perhaps... I've never seen a javascript exception have a `body` property at all.

Comment: I'm wondering if the framework does it then, I just checked one of my projects and thats the value I have used

Comment: Hi @CasparHarmer Thanks for the reply. I tried but getting exact same error and email is not getting triggered.
Is is possible that I'm sending too many parameters that's why getting error? if so please tell me how to send multiple parameter

Comment: try console.log (json.stringify(error)); - or stop the debugger there and examine the error object

Comment: ok I will try that and let you know

Comment: note case on json it would be `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));` if you go that route

Comment: Looks like reading the error is a real pita look here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325258/unable-to-get-aurahandledexception-in-lwc - thanks @PhilHawthorn for the `JSON` thing... getting late here ;)

Comment: Wondering if the cause of the actual error is `mail.setHtmlBody(body);` in the Apex. I see that OP is not setting HTML, rather plain text. Perhaps it should be `mail.setPlainTextBody(body);`

Comment: Hi Guys
while debugging got below message.
message: "Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'phoneNumber' of type 'Integer'" ...
What data type should I use for Phone field